# Ubuntu 14.04 freeze a lot. How to fix it?

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, 14.04

Since the day I installed Ubuntu 14.04 I face frequent freezes. Today it happened for about three times. When it freeze the mouse barely move. It stays that way for a long time. My GPU is Nvidia and I use nvidia-331-updates driver. Here's the last part of my Xorg.0.log :

```
[     4.982] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.982] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     4.982] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event7)
[     4.982] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.982] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     4.982] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event6)
[     4.982] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.982] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     4.982] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event5)
[     4.982] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.982] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     4.982] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[     4.982] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.982] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     4.982] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[     4.982] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     4.982] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     4.983] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04f3:0103 (/dev/input/event3)
[     4.983] (**) HID 04f3:0103: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     4.983] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HID 04f3:0103'
[     4.983] (**) HID 04f3:0103: always reports core events
[     4.983] (**) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Vendor 0x4f3 Product 0x103
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Found keys
[     4.983] (II) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Configuring as keyboard
[     4.983] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/input/input5/event3"
[     4.983] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 04f3:0103" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[     4.983] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     4.983] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     4.983] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     4.983] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HID 04f3:0103 (/dev/input/event4)
[     4.983] (**) HID 04f3:0103: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     4.983] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HID 04f3:0103'
[     4.983] (**) HID 04f3:0103: always reports core events
[     4.983] (**) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Vendor 0x4f3 Product 0x103
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Found 1 mouse buttons
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Found scroll wheel(s)
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Found relative axes
[     4.983] (II) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Forcing relative x/y axes to exist.
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Found absolute axes
[     4.983] (II) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[     4.983] (--) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Found keys
[     4.983] (II) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Configuring as mouse
[     4.983] (II) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Configuring as keyboard
[     4.983] (II) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: Adding scrollwheel support
[     4.983] (**) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[     4.983] (**) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[     4.983] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.1/input/input6/event4"
[     4.983] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HID 04f3:0103" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[     4.983] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     4.983] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     4.983] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     4.983] (II) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: initialized for relative axes.
[     4.983] (WW) evdev: HID 04f3:0103: ignoring absolute axes.
[     4.984] (**) HID 04f3:0103: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     4.984] (**) HID 04f3:0103: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[     4.984] (**) HID 04f3:0103: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     4.984] (**) HID 04f3:0103: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     4.984] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Eee PC WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event10)
[     4.984] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[     4.984] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Eee PC WMI hotkeys'
[     4.984] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[     4.984] (**) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event10"
[     4.984] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[     4.984] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[     4.984] (II) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[     4.984] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input13/event10"
[     4.984] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Eee PC WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[     4.984] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[     4.984] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     4.984] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     5.469] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[     5.469] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[     5.480] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[     5.480] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[     5.606] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}"
[     5.716] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1366+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[     5.965] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[     5.965] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[     5.975] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[     5.975] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   111.974] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   111.974] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   111.985] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   111.985] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   112.293] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   112.293] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   112.303] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   112.303] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   112.313] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +1920+312 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1366+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[   112.348] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +1920+312 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[   112.414] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   112.451] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   112.451] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   112.461] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   112.461] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   113.174] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   113.238] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[   113.319] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   113.319] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   113.330] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[   113.330] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[   114.350] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-34CEB476A3CB596DA76FD7010A029F76732EF824.xkm
[ 22045.005] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 22045.005] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 22045.020] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 22045.020] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 22046.140] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-34CEB476A3CB596DA76FD7010A029F76732EF824.xkm
[ 25657.759] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +1920+312 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[ 25657.901] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 25657.901] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 25657.912] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 25657.912] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 25658.083] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 25658.100] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 25658.120] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 25658.140] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 29278.694] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 29278.694] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 29278.704] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 29278.704] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 29993.885] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select @1366x768 +1920+312 {ViewPortIn=1366x768, ViewPortOut=1366x768+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
[ 29994.026] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SMS19A100 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 29994.026] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 29994.036] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung T23B350 (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[ 29994.037] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[ 30114.150] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 30150.163] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 30194.186] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[ 30390.722] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
```